# Strange memory consumption of C fread / C++ read functions, based on Linux sysinfo data

Tags: c++, linux, file, memory

Okey, I have a weird (in my opinion) behaviour of my program, which is now reduced to just reading 3 arrays from pretty large (approximately 24GB and 48 GB) binary files. The structure of those files is pretty simple, they contain a small header, and 3 arrays after: of type int, int and float, all 3 of size N, where N is very large: 2147483648 for 28 GB file and 4294967296 for 48 GB one.

To track down the memory consumption, I'm using a simple function based on Linux sysinfo, to detect how much free memory I have on each stage of my program (for example after I allocated the arrays to store data and while reading the file). This is the code of the function:

```
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
size_t get_free_memory_in_MB()
{
    struct sysinfo info;
    sysinfo(&info);
    return info.freeram / (1024 * 1024);
}
```

Now straight to the problem: the strange part is that after reading each of 3 arrays from the file using standard C fread function or C++ read function (doesn't matter at all), and checking how much free memory we have after the read, I see that the amount of free memory is heavily reduced (approximately by edges_count * sizeof(int) for the next example).

```
fread(src_ids, sizeof(int), edges_count, graph_file);
cout << "1 test: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;
```

So basically, after reading the whole file my memory consumption according to sysinfo is almost 2x times larger than expected. To illustrate the problem better, I provide the code of the whole function together with it's output; please, read it, it's very small and will illustrate the problem much better.

```
bool load_from_edges_list_bin_file(string _file_name)
{
    bool directed = true;
    int vertices_count = 1;
    long long int edges_count = 0;

    // open the file
    FILE *graph_file = fopen(_file_name.c_str(), "r");
    if(graph_file == NULL)
        return false;

    // just reading a simple header here
    fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&directed), sizeof(bool), 1, graph_file);
    fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&vertices_count), sizeof(int), 1, graph_file);
    fread(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&edges_count), sizeof(long long), 1, graph_file);

    cout << "edges count: " << edges_count << endl;
    cout << "Before graph alloc free memory: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    // allocate the arrays to store the result
    int *src_ids = new int[edges_count];
    int *dst_ids = new int[edges_count];
    _TEdgeWeight *weights = new _TEdgeWeight[edges_count];

    cout << "After graph alloc free memory: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    memset(src_ids, 0, edges_count * sizeof(int));
    memset(dst_ids, 0, edges_count * sizeof(int));
    memset(weights, 0, edges_count * sizeof(_TEdgeWeight));

    cout << "After memset: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    // add edges from file
    fread(src_ids, sizeof(int), edges_count, graph_file);
    cout << "1 test: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    fread(dst_ids, sizeof(int), edges_count, graph_file);
    cout << "2 test: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    fread(weights, sizeof(_TEdgeWeight), edges_count, graph_file);
    cout << "3 test: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    cout << "After actual load: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    delete []src_ids;
    delete []dst_ids;
    delete []weights;

    cout << "After we removed the graph load: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    fclose(graph_file);

    cout << "After we closed the file: " << get_free_memory_in_MB() << " MB" << endl;

    return true;
}
```

So, nothing complicated. Straight to the output (with some comments form me after //). First, for 24GB file:

```
Loading graph...
edges count: 2147483648
Before graph alloc free memory: 91480 MB 
After graph alloc free memory: 91480 MB // allocated memory here, but noting changed, why?
After memset: 66857 MB // ok, we put some data into the memory (memset) and consumed exactly 24 GB, seems correct
1 test: 57658 MB // first read and we have lost 9 GB...
2 test: 48409 MB // -9 GB again...
3 test: 39161 MB // and once more...
After actual load: 39161 MB // we lost in total 27 GB during the reads. How???
After we removed the graph load: 63783 MB // removed the arrays from memory and freed the memory we have allocated
// 24 GB freed, but 27 are still consumed somewhere
After we closed the file: 63788 MB // closing the file doesn't help
Complete!
After we quit the function: 63788 MB // quitting the function doesn't help too.
```

Similar for 48GB file:

```
edges count: 4294967296
Before graph alloc free memory: 91485 MB
After graph alloc free memory: 91485 MB
After memset: 42236 MB
1 test: 23784 MB
2 test: 5280 MB
3 test: 490 MB
After actual load: 490 MB
After we removed the graph load: 49737 MB
After we closed the file: 49741 MB
Complete!
After we quit the function: 49741 MB
```

So, what is happening inside my program?

1) Why so much memory is lost during the reads (both using fread from C and file streams from c++)?

2) Why closing the file doesn't free the memory consumed?

3) Maybe sysinfo is showing me incorrect info?

4) Can this problem be connected to memory fragmentation?

By the way, I'm launching my program on a supercomputer node, on which I have exclusive access (so other people can't influence it), and where are no side-application which can influence my program.

Thank you for reading this!

Comment: Not sure if it's true in linux but in windows once you free memory it does not immediately become available to other programs but rather sits there still allocated to that program in case it needs that memory again.

Comment: You mean that fread function (which is based on Linux system calls as far as I know, can it count as separate program?) may have the same behaviour? well, it requires some investigation.

Comment: everything boils down to OS calls and the OS has a lot of complicated strategies on trying to predict the future needs. You can try running the program again to see if it runs faster and if the memory consumption is the same. If that's the case then chances are you're seeing OS level caching

Comment: sadly I have /var/tmp/slurmd/job611149/slurm_script: line 27: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied, but free -m showed me 43 GB in buff/cache thanks to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly the disk (/page) cache. When you read a file the operating system stores some or all of the contents in memory, thus decreasing the amount of free memory. This is to optimise future reads.

This however does not mean the memory is either used by the process or otherwise unavailable. If/when the memory is needed then it will be freed by the OS and made available.

You should be able to confirm this by tracking the value of the `bufferram` parameter in the sysinfo structure (https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/2-sysinfo/), or by looking at the output of the `free -m` command before and after running your program.

For more detailed information on this, see the following answer: https://superuser.com/questions/980820/what-is-the-difference-between-memfree-and-memavailable-in-proc-meminfo

Comment: Checking bufferram didn't help -- it showed 0 during all program stages. But chinking free -m showed buff/cache = 43828 after program execution